# Preserving arguments when returning data from deferred.then()

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

How can I pass more than 1 argument when returning data in a [deferred.then](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) callback?

```
var data = {
    json: JSON.stringify({
        text: 'some text',
        array: [1, 2, 'three'],
        object: {
            par1: 'another text',
            par2: [3, 2, 'one'],
            par3: {}
        }
    }),
    delay: 3
};

$.ajax({
    url:'/echo/json/',
    data: data,
    type: 'POST'
}).then(function(response, statusText, jqXhr){
    response.text = 'foo';
    // how to return the rest of the arguments correctly?
    return response;
}).done(function(response, statusText, jqXhr){
    console.log(response); // <- altered response
    console.log(statusText); // <- how to pass it along?
    console.log(jqXhr); // <- how to pass it along?
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rv1aydvb/

Comment: Instead of returning the altered data, call the next function directly, with the modified arguments.

Comment: @Barmar Returning an object will still make argument 2 and argument 3 undefined in the `done` callback, right? I'm wondering if there is a way to set them in the `then` callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to return a [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) that is resolved with multiple values using the [`resolveWith` method](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolveWith/). Of course, returning a single (but composite) value is usually cleaner.

```
$.ajax(…).then(function(response) {
    response.text = 'foo';
    return $.Deferred().resolveWith(this, arguments); // if you don't replace but modify vals
    // alternatively,  .resolveWith(this, [response, …]);
}).done(function(response, statusText, jqXhr) {…});
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree that this looks a bit messy. I was just asking out of curiosity

Answer (score 0):

Return an object with the statusText and jqXhr in it. Then you can access them as part of the response object. like so

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/echo/json/',
    data: data,
    type: 'POST'
}).then(function(response, statusText, jqXhr){
    response.text = 'foo';
    return {
        response: response,
        status: statusText,
        jq: jqXhr
    }
}).done(function(response, statusText, jqXhr){
    console.log(response); // <- altered response
    console.log(response.status); // <- undefined
    console.log(response.jq); // <- undefined

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rv1aydvb/3/

Comment: I know that's possible. I'm asking if there is a way to define any argument besides the first one.

Comment: You could return an array instead of just an object.

Comment: Still, it would end up as the first argument

Comment: yeah but the `.done` doesnt have a `statusText` or a `jqXhr`. They are part of the ajax call which is processed in the `.then`

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to access them as separate arguments?